# Why does Outlook 2013 not send my email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

**The problem:**

Outlook 2013 will not send email with a particular symbol, namely a piece of paper with a pencil.

Such a symbol is probably created when I edit an email.  The top symbol with the traditional envelope, sends no trouble, the bottom one sticks in the Outbox and is not sent.

[image: Outbox not sending]

**Question:** What causes this behaviour?  How can I overcome it and send my email.

Comment: Is it a draft? Ah, it's a draft edited within the outbox. Check [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/home_is_where_i_lay_my_head/archive/2012/12/18/outlook-mail-stuck-after-editing-in-outbox.aspx). Disable add-ins to determine which is causing it.

Comment: @Raystafarian You are correct.  It was iCloud, I should have realized - always check (disable) the last thing I installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That icon represents a draft in the outbox, or something edited while it was in the outbox. Try disabling add-ins like iCloud. [source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/home_is_where_i_lay_my_head/archive/2012/12/18/outlook-mail-stuck-after-editing-in-outbox.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a Norton add-in that just appeared.

Try

```
outlook.exe /safe
```

from the command line. If that works, start ruling out you add-ins.